# how to find xor key/algorithm, for a given hex?

Tags: algorithm, encryption, hex, xor, deobfuscation

So i have this hex: B0 32 B6 B4 37

I know this hex is obfuscated with some key/algorithm.

I also know this hex is equal to: 61 64 6d 69 6e (admin)

How can i calculate the XOR key for this?

Comment: aint sure i got your question right, but if you mean `"admin" xor ?KEY? = B0 32 B6 B4 37` ??? if yes, then the answer is really easy cause xor is abelian operation, then `"admin" xor b0 32 b6 b4 37 = ?KEY?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write out the binary representation, you can see the pattern:

```
encoded     decoded
10110000 -> 01100001
00110010 -> 01100100
```

Notice that the bit patterns have the same number of bits before and after. To decode, you just bitwise rotate one bit left. So the value shifts left one place and the most significant bit wraps around to the least significant place. To encode, just do the opposite.

```
int value, encoded_value;

encoded_value = 0xB0;
value = ((encoded_value << 1) | (encoded_value >> 7)) & 255;
// value will be 0x61;
encoded_value = ((value >> 1) | (value << 7)) & 255;
```